# How to correctly load SP JS resources in a code snippet

Tags: 2013, javascript

I have inserted the following javascript into a masterpage, however I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I believe that this might be because the SP JS files are not correctly loaded at that time, I still see them on F12 after the page finishes loading.

http://screencast.com/t/Akb7KKpn5p2

My code is as follows:

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var path = document.location.href
    console.log(path);
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext('http://myservername/centrodeprocesos/procesos');
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ImagenesDeFondo');     
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);        
    clientContext.load(collListItem);        
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));       

});


function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();        
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }
    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: check this one if resolve the issue: http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/30/how-to-properly-reference-sp-js-in-a-master-page/

Comment: Try comment 'console.log( "ready!" );' - it is unsupported in some IE

Comment: My five cents is on that you have not loaded jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your $(document).ready call with a function with some name (let it be Func1) and then call it this way:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Func1, 'sp.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at this answer: [Answer to - SP.ClientContext is always “undefined” in JSLink functions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/86210/5658)

Relatively to Your "How to correctly load SP JS resources" question - saw answer here, but cannot google it right now.

The answer was that - the most correctly way to load JS snippet on masterpage is to use user control, technique is described here: [Adding jQuery to Every Page in SharePoint with Delegate Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx)

SharePoint Mastergpages have "AdditionalPageHead" section. Using User Control from WSP we can deploy additional code and load it on every masterpage. It is better becouse You don't modify original masterpage directly(it is not recommended), and have abiblity to turn on or off feature on web/site/farm scopes. It is described by the link

Answer (score -1):

Try to load 'sp.js' file on back-end code like this:

```
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
            {
                writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/sp.js", true));
                writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/sp.core.js", true));
                writer.Write(BindScript("~site/Style Library/script/SP.Runtime.js", true));

                base.Render(writer);
            }
```

`private string BindScript(string scriptUrl, bool PickFromSiteCollection)
        {
            if (PickFromSiteCollection)
                scriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url, scriptUrl);
            else
                scriptUrl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.Url, scriptUrl);

            return string.Format(@"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}""></script>", scriptUrl);
        }`