# Unable to get property 'get_current' of undefined or null reference in JSLink on list view

Tags: sharepoint-server, jslink

we need to filter list view items based on some conditions for which we need current context(sp.ClientContext). but we are getting undefined or null reference. we have also followed the solution provided by Vadim Gremyachev [on Stack exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75106/sp-clientcontext-is-always-undefined-in-jslink-functions)

but as soon as the sp.js loads; list view also gets load. so whatever condition we want to apply to filter out list view items does not work as the required code starts working after list view loads.

Please suggest how we can solve this problem.

Comment: show your code; Vadims answer runs in OnPreRender, **before** the View is built

Comment: As of now we are executing the same code given by Vadim. as soon as the  sp.js loads view gets diplayed and code related to current context execute after that.                                                                                            function OnPreRenderDocItemTemplate(renderCtx) {
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadContext, 'sp.js');
        function loadContext() {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = context.get_web();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem (which I also added as an answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/193948/8992)) is to add whatever JSOM files you need loaded to your JSLink, to ensure they are loaded before your CSR script is loaded and runs.

For instance, I needed to use `SP.WorkflowServices` in a CSR script, and that requires 3 files (SP.js, SP.Runtime.js, SP.WorkflowServices.js), so I just added those three files to my field's JSLink:

```
clienttemplates.js|sp.js|sp.runtime.js|sp.workflowservices.js|~site/path/to/my-csr-script.js
```

JSLink then takes care of loading those files in order, and then `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` works from within your CSR code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all of these scripts are loaded on the parent page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then as an extra step, wait for sp.js to load before executing get_current()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init(), "sp.js");
});
```

You can also try this function:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("init");
```